# files upload at form submit button with Plupload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plupload

I am using the Latest version of Plupload (2.1) - UI widget

when i click upload files, it uploads all files correctly.

but when i try to upload files with my Form submit button. it doesn't work. it just showing a little bit uploading of files and then eventually submit the forms without completing the file upload.

here is my code :

```
jj = jQuery.noConflict();

jj(function() {
  jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload({
    runtimes: "html5,flash,silverlight,html4",
    url: "/external/uploader-new/upload.php",
    max_file_size: "10mb",
    chunk_size: "1mb",
    unique_names: true,
    filters: [
      {
        title: "jpg,xls,csv,doc,pdf,docx,xlsx",
        extensions: "jpg,xls,csv,doc,pdf,docx,xlsx"
      }
    ],
    flash_swf_url: "/external/uploader-new/js/Moxie.swf",
    silverlight_xap_url: "/external/uploader-new/js/Moxie.xap"
  });

  // Handle the case when form was submitted before uploading has finished
  jj("form").submit(function(e) {
    // Files in queue upload them first

    if (jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload("getFiles").length > 0) {
      // When all files are uploaded submit form
      jj("#flash_uploader_other").on("complete", function() {
        jj("form").submit();
      });
      jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload("start");
    }
  });
});
```

Please help!!

Thanks

its working now
I replaced the following code

```
jj("form").submit(function(e) {
  // Files in queue upload them first
  if (jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload("getFiles").length > 0) {
    // When all files are uploaded submit form
    jj("#flash_uploader_other").on("complete", function() {
      jj("form").submit();
    });
    jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload("start");
  }
});
```

With this code :

```
jj("form").submit(function(e) {
  var uploader = jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload("getUploader");
  // Validate number of uploaded files
  if (uploader.total.uploaded == 0) {
    // Files in queue upload them first
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
      // When all files are uploaded submit form
      uploader.bind("UploadProgress", function() {
        jj("#flash_uploader_other").on("complete", function() {
          jj("form").submit();
        });
      });

      jj("#flash_uploader_other").plupload("start");
    } else {
      jj("form").submit();
    }
    //alert('You must at least upload one file.');

    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: ah finally its working :)